# Moving Car Animation Using Mapbox in flutter

Tags: flutter, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I've implementing MabBox SDK with one of my flutter app.  It has car live tracking screen, which will update car marker position on map based on location received. Here we would like to show car moving animation like [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/562/1*ICnln5X09RWdwqkbxm6KaQ.gif) .

I've gone through the MabBox documents, Couldn't find any related document for our use cases. Then I've gone through google's [flutter_animarker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker) which doesn't support Mabbox. Anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finished car moving animation. Here is the final code.

```
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

LatLng? oldLatLng;
bool isCarAnimating = false;

onLocationChange(String latLng) async {
  currentLatLng = LatLng(
      double.parse(latLng.split(',')[0]), double.parse(latLng.split(',')[1]));

  if (cabMarkerSymbol != null && !isCarAnimating)
    _animateCabIcon(oldLatLng!, currentLatLng!);
}

_animateCabIcon(LatLng start, LatLng end) async {
  try {
    AnimationController controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 3));
    Animation animation;
    var tween = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1);
    animation = tween.animate(controller);

    animation.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        oldLatLng = end;
        isCarAnimating = false;
      } else if (status == AnimationStatus.forward) {
        isCarAnimating = true;
      }
    });
    controller.forward();
    var bearing = getBearing(start, end);

    animation.addListener(() async {
      var v = animation.value;
      var lng = v * end.longitude + (1 - v) * start.longitude;
      var lat = v * end.latitude + (1 - v) * start.latitude;

      var latLng = LatLng(lat, lng);

      var carSymbolOptions = SymbolOptions(
        geometry: latLng,
        iconRotate: bearing,
      );
      await _completer.future
          .then((map) => map.updateSymbol(carMarkerSymbol!, carSymbolOptions));
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

double getBearing(LatLng start, LatLng end) {
  var lat1 = start.latitude * math.pi / 180;
  var lng1 = start.longitude * math.pi / 180;
  var lat2 = end.latitude * math.pi / 180;
  var lng2 = end.longitude * math.pi / 180;

  var dLon = (lng2 - lng1);
  var y = math.sin(dLon) * math.cos(lat2);
  var x = math.cos(lat1) * math.sin(lat2) -
      math.sin(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.cos(dLon);
  var bearing = math.atan2(y, x);
  bearing = (bearing * 180) / math.pi;
  bearing = (bearing + 360) % 360;

  return bearing;
}
```

Comment: Also available flutter plugin https://pub.dev/packages/mmi_animap